# Meaning of "feature has null Z values" when using Move tool of Editor in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

i am trying to move a polygon from a location to another location. when using the move tool (editor) in ArcGIS, I place the x and y values to where i will move the polygon. however, when pressing enter, a message stating that the feature has null z values appear. how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide some additional detail.  What storage type are your features in?  Is it a shapefile, geodatabase, etc?  What projection?

Answer (score 2):

Seems that the feature you are trying to edit was defined with Z value (elevation), yet the polygon doesn't have any z value, hence null.